# How to view the data stored in NSData?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am pretty new to Objective C. I am analyzing the iOS App code and using xCode, I kept debug pointers and I am actually trying to view the data stored in an NSData variable.

But I am seeing the below value,

```
NSData * data= [NSData dataWithBytes:temp length:32];
return data;

(lldb) po data
<c5909c89 ff06ea8b 8a037ac7 cd7f04c8 0c74bb7b 0a9b34ea c208f391 173a84ba>
```

How can I actually see the data stored in the data variable? I have tried applying various encodings to decode the NSData but that also failed. Please help me on this. I know it stores 32 bytes of data, but I would like to know what data is stored in each byte? It will help me in hardcoding an NSData variable. Can someone tell me how to hardcode the NSData var based on the below output?

Comment: `po` did show you the bytes. What more do you want?

Comment: @Gereon Thanks for the reply. How to convert the bytes to string?

Comment: I would like to hardcode the NSData. So If I understand the String it might help me with the hardcoding part. Based on the above data, how can I hardcode an NSData variable in objective code?

Comment: Those bytes cannot be converted to string except this hexadecimal `"<c5909..."` representation.

Comment: @vadian Could you tell me how to hardcode an NSData? I would like the variable data to always have the same data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hardcode the data with an `UInt8` buffer

```
UInt8 bytes[] = {0xc5, 0x90, 0x9c, 0x89, 0xff, 0x06, 0xea, 0x8b, 0x8a, 0x03, 0x7a, 0xc7, 0xcd, 0x7f, 0x04, 0xc8, 0x0c, 0x74, 0xbb, 0x7b, 0x0a, 0x9b, 0x34, 0xea, 0xc2, 0x08, 0xf3, 0x91, 0x17, 0x3a, 0x84, 0xba};
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:&bytes length:32];
NSLog(@"%@", data);
```